# MSSQL 2005 How can i group these data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by, rank, row-number

I have a table like this in SQL SERVER 2005

```
No WorkOrder StartDateTime     EndDateTime       
======================================================
1  WO111111  2019-01-01 07:00  2019-01-01 08:00  
2  WO111111  2019-01-01 08:00  2019-01-01 08:30  
3  WO222222  2019-01-01 08:30  2019-01-01 09:30  
4  WO222222  2019-01-01 09:30  2019-01-01 10:00  
6  WO222222  2019-01-01 10:00  2019-01-01 12:00 
7  WO111111  2019-01-01 12:00  2019-01-01 17:00
```

How Can I get the table below

```
WorkOrder StartDateTime     EndDateTime
============================================
WO111111  2019-01-01 07:00  2019-01-01 08:30
WO222222  2019-01-01 08:30  2019-01-01 12:00
WO111111  2019-01-01 12:00  2019-01-01 17:00
```

I tried row_number() and rank(), and it did't work.

```
DECLARE @Tmp TABLE (No int, WorkOrder varchar(20), StartDateTime datetime, EndDateTime datetime)
insert into @Tmp values(1,'WO111111','2019-01-01 07:00','2019-01-01 08:00')
insert into @Tmp values(2,'WO111111','2019-01-01 08:00','2019-01-01 08:30')
insert into @Tmp values(3,'WO222222','2019-01-01 08:30','2019-01-01 09:30')
insert into @Tmp values(4,'WO222222','2019-01-01 09:30','2019-01-01 10:00')
insert into @Tmp values(5,'WO222222','2019-01-01 10:00','2019-01-01 12:00')
insert into @Tmp values(6,'WO111111','2019-01-01 12:00','2019-01-01 17:00')
select * from @Tmp;
select g,WorkOrder,min(StartDateTime)StartDateTime,Max(EndDateTime)EndDateTime
From(
  select rank()over(order by WorkOrder)as g,* from @Tmp
)a group by g,WorkOrder
```

Comment: Could you show us your `ROW_NUMBER` and `RANK` attempts please?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: `row_number()` won't help you here. You need `lag()`.

Comment: A very common problem - [gaps and islands](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/solving-gaps-and-islands-enhanced-window-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now knowing you're on SQL Server 2005, you'll need to rely on `outer apply` to make the arbitrary join required here to determine the relative previous record.

You haven't outlined the predication here. But guessing from the output you're looking for the first `WorkOrder` of each group, which in this case appears to be a run of times until a different `WorkOrder` appears.

The approach below uses `apply` to obtain the previous record using `top 1`, specifically `outer apply` to ensure we don't lose the first record (think of it like a `left join`).

The `apply` iterator is almost always overlooked and often forgotten. But is a **very** powerful tool when you need iteration without a concrete join predicate like a key. I've used this approach on big tables to get to solve the "top n problem", finding it sometimes performs better than what's built-in.

**Note that I've chosen `No` as my tie-breaker.**

```
CREATE TABLE #WorkOrders (
   No             INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
  ,WorkOrder      VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
  ,StartDateTime  DATETIME NOT NULL
  ,EndDateTime    DATETIME NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #WorkOrders (WorkOrder, StartDateTime, EndDateTime)
VALUES  ('WO111111','20190101 07:00','20190101 08:00')
        ,('WO111111','20190101 08:00','20190101 08:30')
        ,('WO111111','20190101 08:30','20190101 09:30')
        ,('WO222222','20190101 08:30','20190101 09:30')
        ,('WO222222','20190101 09:30','20190101 10:00')
        ,('WO222222','20190101 10:00','20190101 12:30')
        ,('WO111111','20190101 12:00','20190101 12:30')

SELECT  wo.WorkOrder
     ,  wo.StartDateTime
     ,  wo.EndDateTime
  FROM  #WorkOrders AS wo 
        OUTER APPLY (
          SELECT  TOP(1)
                  * 
            FROM  #WorkOrders AS wo2 
           WHERE  wo2.StartDateTime < wo.StartDateTime 
           ORDER  BY wo2.StartDateTime DESC, No DESC
        ) AS prev
 WHERE prev.WorkOrder IS NULL
       OR prev.WorkOrder <> wo.WorkOrder

DROP TABLE #WorkOrders;
```

Comment: I can't use lag() In SQL Server 2005

Comment: @rxyes Adjusted my answer to use `outer apply`. I didn't realize your version limitation until after your question update.

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with a self join and a `SUM` window function. First determine when the `WorkOrder` value changes to be able to group by considering the order of `No`, then just group by with `MIN` and `MAX` to smash the dates intervals.

```
;WITH LaggedWorkOrder AS
(
    SELECT
        T1.WorkOrder,
        T1.StartDateTime,
        T1.EndDateTime,
        T1.No,
        WorkOrderChange = CASE 
            WHEN T2.WorkOrder = T1.WorkOrder THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 END
    FROM
        @Tmp AS T1
        LEFT JOIN @Tmp AS T2 ON T1.No - 1 = T2.No
),
WorkOrderGroups AS
(
    SELECT
        L.WorkOrder,
        L.StartDateTime,
        L.EndDateTime,
        L.No,
        WorkOrderGroup = SUM(L.WorkOrderChange) OVER (ORDER BY L.No ASC)
    FROM
        LaggedWorkOrder AS L
)
SELECT
    W.WorkOrder,
    StartDateTime = MIN(W.StartDateTime),
    EndDateTime = MAX(W.EndDateTime)
FROM
    WorkOrderGroups AS W
GROUP BY
    W.WorkOrderGroup,
    W.WorkOrder
ORDER BY
    W.WorkOrderGroup
```

Results:

```
WorkOrder   StartDateTime               EndDateTime
WO111111    2019-01-01 07:00:00.000     2019-01-01 08:30:00.000
WO222222    2019-01-01 08:30:00.000     2019-01-01 12:00:00.000
WO111111    2019-01-01 12:00:00.000     2019-01-01 17:00:00.000
```

The intermediate CTE results are these:

**LaggedWorkOrder** (see whenever WorkOrder changes value):

```
WorkOrder   StartDateTime               EndDateTime                 No  WorkOrderChange
WO111111    2019-01-01 07:00:00.000     2019-01-01 08:00:00.000     1   1
WO111111    2019-01-01 08:00:00.000     2019-01-01 08:30:00.000     2   0
WO222222    2019-01-01 08:30:00.000     2019-01-01 09:30:00.000     3   1
WO222222    2019-01-01 09:30:00.000     2019-01-01 10:00:00.000     4   0
WO222222    2019-01-01 10:00:00.000     2019-01-01 12:00:00.000     5   0
WO111111    2019-01-01 12:00:00.000     2019-01-01 17:00:00.000     6   1
```

**WorkOrderGroups** (generate grouping values for MAX/MIN):

```
WorkOrder   StartDateTime               EndDateTime                 No  WorkOrderGroup
WO111111    2019-01-01 07:00:00.000     2019-01-01 08:00:00.000     1   1
WO111111    2019-01-01 08:00:00.000     2019-01-01 08:30:00.000     2   1
WO222222    2019-01-01 08:30:00.000     2019-01-01 09:30:00.000     3   2
WO222222    2019-01-01 09:30:00.000     2019-01-01 10:00:00.000     4   2
WO222222    2019-01-01 10:00:00.000     2019-01-01 12:00:00.000     5   2
WO111111    2019-01-01 12:00:00.000     2019-01-01 17:00:00.000     6   3
```

---

**PD:** Please consider **upgrading the server version**, 2005 ended support on April 2016 already.

Comment: @rxyes fixed, try now.

Comment: order wrong ?
this line => WorkOrderGroup = SUM(L.WorkOrderChange) OVER (ORDER BY L.No ASC)

Comment: @rxyes the order is OK as for my understanding of your desired outcome, maybe if you could explain in detail how you want your output, I can update the answer accordingly.

Comment: sum()over() is not supported in sql server 2005

Answer (score -1):

**Get expected output using group by min, max**

```
SELECT WorkOrder, min(StartDateTime),max(EndDateTime) FROM `tb` group by WorkOrder
```

> Output

==============

## WorkOrder StartDateTime     EndDateTime

```
WO111111  2019-01-01 07:00  2019-01-01 08:30
WO222222  2019-01-01 08:30  2019-01-01 12:00
WO111111  2019-01-01 12:00  2019-01-01 17:00
```